# Как отловить завершение рендеринга?

Tags: reactjs

массив данных полученный ajax'ом рендерится в цикле

```
{self.props.users.map((u, i) =>
    <li key={i}>u</li>
)}
```

после отрисовки требуется навешивать сторонний скрипт:

```
...
let list = document.querySelectorAll('.myclass');
...
```

методы `componentDidMount` и `componentWillReceiveProps` отрабатывают до появления списка в DOM

как отловить завершение отрисовки всего списка?

Comment: Например, отказаться от использования react и перейти на angular или knockout...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да в ангулярах свои костыли и велосипеды ) плавали, знаем (С)

Comment: componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate. componentDidMount отрабатывает после появления списка в доме, вот только делает он это один раз при начальном рендере

Comment: вам может быть полезно вот это: https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/postrender_with_componentdidupdate.html

Comment: Плюс я бы выбирал то на что стороннюю штуку навешивать не через document.querySelector а через refs или findDOMNode, чтоб оно как-то поинкапсулированнее было